# SAP Cloud Platform: OData provisioning. How do I setup for an external user?

Tags: odata, provisioning, sap-cloud-platform

I've set up access to an SAP Gateway OData service using the OData Provisioning service. This works fine with Basic Authentication when I'm logged into SAP Cloud Platform.

The question is: How do I set this up for the outside world, as I set up the same call via postman and I'm getting a  ***Note: Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is turned off. Press the button to proceed.***  error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the **Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is turned off. Press the button to proceed**. error is due to a failure to authenticate and actually redirects you to the login page.

I think the following page explains the flow: https://help.sap.com/viewer/a7c6d8a0bd1f415887f6246d8cf8e68e/Cloud/en-US/eeef740e63d143059892c93ed3cb473f.html

Basically, to call you OData Provisioning service, you will need to provide credentials to a SAP Cloud Platform user account that holds the GW_Role (I think) and not to your SAP Gateway system.

Now talking about Postman, if you want to execute a POST/PUT/DELETE, you will first need to fetch a **X-CSRF-Token** before being able to execute any kind of changes in your data.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/a7c6d8a0bd1f415887f6246d8cf8e68e/Cloud/en-US/d2e706bd63c043c7b7ae1d2dc830bb79.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've added my SCP P user in the GW_User role and included my username + password in Postman. Still the same issue. Note this is a GET request so for this the X-CSRF-Token won't be needed, right?

Comment: Ok, I think I found some additional elements. 
When consuming the ODP destination, you will need to use OAuth (as BasicAuthentication actually is not allowed apparently).

This was raised in the following posts: 
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/08/consume-sap-gateway-odata-service-in-sap-cloud-platform-workflow/
https://answers.sap.com/questions/12636602/403-forbidden-with-odata-provisioning-using-client.html

The first link explain the OAuth configuration in ODP, and the second explains how to use Oauth from Postman

Comment: I followed the blog. Setup my oauth_client. Got the token. Added the token to the Bearer in the Authorization of the next call...  This gets a 403 forbidden error... Oh, and I also added the oauth_client user into the GW role. Still no joy.

Comment: Does anything need to happen to the oData provisioning destination?  How exactly is the oAuth DESTINATION setup for the oData provisioning?

Comment: Hi @AdamHarkus Let me try that out when I get back home next week.

Comment: Hi @AdamHarkus, sorry for the very very late response. 
I was able to execute a GET from Postman on one of the ES5 system is exposing for demo purpose using Basic Authentication.
The destination URL was https://sapes5.sapdevcenter.com/sap/iwbep?sap-client=002 for the OData Provisioning destination.
You can note the end of the URL with the **/sap/iwbep?sap-client=xxx** which was required.